# ajax doesn't work on galaxy s4 with cordova 3.0

Tags: android, ajax, cordova, galaxy

I'm starting to work with cordova and jqmobile.

I had followed some guides and some posts here but none of them are helping me.
I have created a simple test app with an ajax call that return some values. It works fine with some android's phones (i.e. Google nexus with android 4.2 , galaxy ace with android 2.3 ) but it doesn't wors with my galaxy s4.

What am I missing ??

This is my index.js

```
var deviceReadyDeferred = $.Deferred();
var jqmReadyDeferred = $.Deferred();
document.addEventListener('mainpage',deviceReady(),false);
function deviceReady(){
    deviceReadyDeferred.resolve();
}
$(document).on('mobileinit',function(){
    jqmReadyDeferred.resolve();
});
$.when(deviceReadyDeferred,jqmReadyDeferred).then(doWhenBothFrameworksLoaded());
function doWhenBothFrameworksLoaded (){
    $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
    $.support.cors = true;
    loadRepos();
}
```

the `loadRepos()` function contains the ajax.

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
    <script src="assets/jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/jquery.mobile/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

  <div data-role="page" id="mainpage">

    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" id="deviceready">
      <h1>Ticket Test</h1>
      <div data-role='navbar'>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#mymenu" data-inline='true' data-icon="grid">Menu</a></li>
          <li><a href="#popupMenu" data-rel="popup"
              data-role="button" data-inline="true"
              data-transition="slideup" data-icon="gear" data-theme="e">Options</a></li>
          <li><a href="#mycerca" data-icon="search"
              data-inline='true'>Cerca</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
      <h2>Dashboard</h2>
      <table id="dashboard" data-role="table" data-mode="columntoggle"
        class="ui-responsive table-stroke" data-filter="true">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th data-priority="2">Company</th>
            <th data-priority="3">Queue</th>
            <th data-priority="4">Receiver</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in the following line:
`document.addEventListener('mainpage',deviceReady(),false);`

It should read:
`document.addEventListener('mainpage',deviceReady,false);`

I.e. function name, not function invocation.